# In python's argparse module, how can I disable printing subcommand choices between curly brackets?

Tags: python, argparse

How can I disable printing subcommand choices, the ones between curly brackets? Using an example at http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#sub-commands, the normal output is:

```
usage:  [-h] {foo,bar} ...

optional arguments:
-h, --help  show this help message and exit

subcommands:
{foo,bar}   additional help
```

What I want is to print this:

```
usage:  [-h] {foo,bar} ...

optional arguments:
-h, --help  show this help message and exit

subcommands:
```

Removing just the last line.

Answer (score 8):

To avoid spamming my users with the huge ugly curly-braced list of dozens of sub-commands, I simply set the `metavar` attribute of the subcommand object. My code looks like:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Stack Overflow example')
subs = parser.add_subparsers()
subs.metavar = 'subcommand'
sub = subs.add_parser('one', help='does something once')
sub = subs.add_parser('two', help='does something twice')
parser.parse_args()
```

And the output of running this script with a single `-h` argument is:

```
usage: tmp.py [-h] subcommand ...

Stack Overflow example

positional arguments:
  subcommand
    one       does something once
    two       does something twice

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

The result is not exactly what you illustrate as your best desired case, but I think that it may be the closest you can get without subclassing `argparse.ArgumentParser` and overriding the things you need adjusted, which would be messy work.

Answer (score 0):

Override ArgumentParser.print_usage() with your own method to print whatever, however you want.  If all you want to do is eliminate the last line, call the original version, capture the results (by sending it to a file) and print just the part(s) you want.